# PowerShell loop displays wrong value

Tags: powershell, loops

This PowerShell code is supposed to take a user's selection from the console, and evaluate if the selection does equals "4.  ALL" or single selection numbers 1-3. If the selection is '4' I need to cycle through all $Roundtrip variables and display all the names. If only 1 number is selected it should only display the name for that selected single selection.

I have a 'if' statement to check if the selected $Roundtrip value is in the $rtOptions array and if $Roundtrip equals 4. If this true loop through each item in $rtOptions array and run runIRCSync function, which would display each roundtrips name. I've added a function 'clearParams' to reset the $displayName to null after each loop iteration If the selection is not 4 it is a single selection and handled by the 'else' display numbers selection. This is not what's happening. Regardless of number selected from the console it always returns the wrong display name.

code:

```
$Roundtrip = -1
$rtOptions = @(1,2,3,4)
$SelectionMade = "false"
    
function clearParams{
    $displayName = $null
}

function runIRCSync{
# Print roundtrip name
'Roundtrip Name ' + $displayName
}

while($SelectionMade -eq "false") {
    
    "Select Roundtrip to run"
    "1.  Apples"
    "2.  Banannas"
    "3.  Canteloup"
    "4.  ALL"

    # Insert a blank line for visual spacing
    "    "
    $Roundtrip = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Roundtrip to run from list above."

    "You have chosen to run the round trip for "
    "  " + $Roundtrip
 

    # Process Roundtrip selection

    # Check if roundtrip is in $rtOptions array AND equals 4
    if($rtOptions -contains $Roundtrip -and $Roundtrip -eq 4) {
        $SelectionMade = "true"
        #Inside loop the Roundtrip display name in runIRCSync always returns "Apples"
        for ($i=0; $i -lt $rtOptions.length; $i++) {
            'Roundtrip no: ' + $rtOptions[$i]
            $Roundtrip = $rtOptions[$i]
            # Run 
            runIRCSync
            clearParams
        }
    }elseif($rtOptions -contains $Roundtrip -and $Roundtrip -ne 4){
        $SelectionMade = "true"
        $Roundtrip = $rtOptions
        runIRCSync
        clearParams
    }
}
    
if($Roundtrip -eq 1) {
        $displayName =  "Apple"

    } elseif($Roundtrip -eq 2) {
        $displayName =  "Banannas"
        
    } elseif($Roundtrip -eq 3) {
        $displayName =  "Cantaloupe"
        
    } elseif($Roundtrip -eq 4) {
        $displayName =  "All"
}
```

Returned results to console

````
```1.  Apples
```2.  Banannas
```3.  Cantaloupe
```4.  ALL

```Example returned code    
```Enter Roundtrip to run from list above.: 3
```You have chosen to run the round trip for 
```  3
```ERROR it displays the wrong name. Should be Cantaloupe
```Roundtrip Name All



What I expect to happen for the '4' selection
1. User is prompted with a numbered list selection
2. The user selects 4
3. The console will display all the names in each numbered list array

What I expect to happen for all other numbers in $rtOptions array
1. User is prompted with a numbered list selection
2. The user selects one digit NOT 4
3. The console will display that numbered items name
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your main problem is that your `$displayName` variable isn't defined until *after* your `while` loop, so your `runIRCSync` function never sees a value.
- However, your code can be greatly streamlined to make it more modular and to eliminate duplication - please see the source-code comments.

```bash
# Define an [ordered] hashtable that maps option numbers to
# display names.
$placeHolderForAll = 'All'
$rtOptions = [ordered] @{
  '1' = 'Apple'
  '2' = 'Banana'
  '3' = 'Canteloupe'
  '4' = $placeHolderForAll
}    

# Define the function *with a parameter* instead of referencing a variable
# from the calling scope.
function runIRCSync {
  param([string] $displayName)
  # Print roundtrip name
  'Roundtrip Name ' + $displayName
}

# Menu loop.
while ($true) { # Loop indefinitely, until the user enters "Q"

  # Print the options, using the hashtable.
  @"

-----------------------
Select Roundtrip to run
$($rtOptions.GetEnumerator().ForEach({ '{0}. {1}' -f $_.Key, $_.Value }) -join "`n")

"@

  # Prompt the user.
  $Roundtrip = (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Roundtrip to run from list above or Q to quit").Trim()

  # Rule out blank input...
  if (-not $Roundtrip) { Write-Warning "Input must not be blank. Please try again."; continue }
  # ... or quit, if requested.
  elseif ($Roundtrip -eq 'q') { break }

  @"
You have chosen to run the round trip for
  $Roundtrip
"@

  # Look up the display name for the chosen option.
  $displayName = $rtOptions[$RoundTrip]
  # Re-prompt, if there is no such option.
  if (-not $displayName) { 
    Write-Warning "Unknown option: $RoundTrip. Please try again."
    continue
  }

  # Process the Roundtrip selection.
  if ($displayName -eq $placeHolderForAll) { # implies that 4 was entered.
    # Get all display names other than 'ALL' and call runIRCSync with each.
    foreach ($displayName in $rtOptions.Values -ne $placeHolderForAll) {
      runIRCSync $displayName
    }
  }
  else {
    # Call runIRCSync with the display name for the chosen option.
    runIRCSync $displayName
  }
}
```

Note:

- In order to enumerate the *entries* (key-value pairs) of a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables), a call to its `.GetEnumerator()` method is necessary (by default, PowerShell considers hashtables / dictionaries to be *single* objects).
- The [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) can then be used to operate on each key-value pair (instances of [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String), which have `.Key` and `.Value` properties), as shown above.